# XML code into DTD code

Tags: xml, dtd

Well-formed code of XML is given below which is showing the hierarchy of different courses in Computer Science Department of University. I have convert the xml code into dtd code. Where am I wrong.

**My XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<University Name="Virtual University of Pakistan">
  <Departments>
         <Department name="Computer Science">
          <Courses>
            <Under-Graduate>
              <Course name="Introduction to Computing">CS101</Course>
              <Course name="Introduction to Programming ">CS201</Course>
              <Course name="Data Structures">CS301</Course>
              <Course name="Object Oriented Programming">CS304</Course>
              <Course name="Data Communication">CS601</Course>   
            </Under-Graduate>

            <Graduate>
              <Course name="Theory of Computation">CS701</Course>
              <Course name="Advanced Operating Systems">CS703</Course>
              <Course name="Software Quality Assurance">CS706</Course>
              <Course name="Distributed DBMS">CS712</Course>
              <Course name="Advanced Computer Networks">CS716</Course>
            </Graduate>     
          </Courses>
     </Department>
  </Departments>
```

**My DTD Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE University> 

<!ELEMENT Name "Virtual University of Pakistan">
    <!ELEMENT Departments>
        <!ELEMENT Department name "Computer Science">
            <!ELEMENT Courses>
                <!ELEMENT Under-Graduate>
                    <!ELEMENT name "Introduction to Computing">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS101">
                    <!ELEMENT name "Introduction to Programming">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS201">
                    <!ELEMENT name "Data Structures">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS301">
                    <!ELEMENT name "Object Oriented Programming">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS304">
                    <!ELEMENT name "Data Communication">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS601>
                <!ELEMENT Graduate>
                    <!ELEMENT name "Theory of Computation">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS701">
                    <!ELEMENT name "Advanced Operating Systems">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS703">
                    <!ELEMENT name "Software Quality Assurance">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS706">
                    <!ELEMENT name "Distributed DBMS">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS712">
                    <!ELEMENT name "Advanced Computer Networks">
                        <!ENTITY Course "CS716">
```

I have created an XML code and convert that XML code into DTD code. So Where am I wrong in my DTD code.

Comment: DTD describes the structure not the content.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial problem is that what you are producing is not syntactically a DTD.  A related problem is that it appears not to be semantically a DTD, either.  (It's hard to tell for sure, since the XML spec does not define any semantics for the character sequence you are providing.)

You should read a tutorial introduction to XML DTDs.  If you are learning XML DTDs in a course (the question does sound like homework), perhaps your instructor can recommend one.  Perhaps your instructor has already done so, or provided one.  If you're not in a course, you can find many such tutorials on the Web.  Some people are partial to "A gentle introduction to XML," which Lou Burnard and I produced, but the most recent version of that document describes Relax NG compact syntax, rather than DTDs, so you will need to find an older version.  One such is available from [The Cover Pages](http://xml.coverpages.org/TEI-GentleIntroXML.pdf); DTDs are described in sections 1.4-1.7 of that version.

While reading the tutorial, pay attention to the following topics, which will show you some of the things going wrong in your current effort.

- How many declarations can a conforming DTD have for a given element type?
- What keyword is used for declaring the valid content of an element type?
- What syntax is used to declare the valid content?
- What keyword is used for declaring attributes for an element?  What's the syntax of an attribute declaration?

Good luck.